# Insert/Update linked SQL Server Tables from Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

is it possible to insert/update data into SQL Server tables from Access front end? If so how?

I have a linked sql server table in access db which I want to update using an unbound access form, what is the best way to doing this?

Comment: Do you have the required permissions to update via an `UPDATE` string? Is this application due to be released to end users? If it is I hope the answer to the above is either 'No' or that the end users don't. Depending on the complexity of the update probably calling a stored procedure would be my method of choice.

Comment: @Simon1979 Yes, I do have required permissions. Once I hit the Submit button on ACCESS form I do see the data in SQL Server table. But when I close the ACCESS db, the data I updated is deleted. This app is for a very limited use, until we find a better solution. This is a temp fix. How would you update/insert a linked sql server table from access using stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would delete on exiting the database, unless it isn't committing the transaction, though not sure how you would actually do this, maybe something in the connection string to the table.

A very simplistic stored procedure route would look like this:

Create your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SimpleUpdateExample 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @NewValue int,
    @WhereCriteria1 int,
    @WhereCriteria2 varchar(10),
    @Ret int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE tbl_YourTable
        SET UpdatedField = @NewValue
        WHERE FirstCriteriaField = @WhereCriteria1 
                And SecondCriteriaField = @WhereCriteria2

        SET @Ret = @@ROWCOUNT

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    SET @Ret = -1
END CATCH

END
```

Create a function to call the procedure:

```
Function UpdateData(iNewValue As Integer, iCrtieria1 As Integer, _
    strCriteria2 As String) As Long
On Error GoTo Err_Handle


Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;" _
    & "DATABASE=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

cnn.Open cnn.ConnectionString

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.usp_SimpleUpdateExample"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@NewValue", adInteger, _
    adParamInput, , iNewValue)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@WhereCriteria1", 20, _
    adParamInput, , iCrtieria1)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@WhereCriteria2", adVarChar, _
    adParamInput, , strCriteria2)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@Ret", adInteger, adParamOutput)
cmd.Parameters.Append param


cmd.Execute

UpdateData = cmd.Parameters("@Ret")


Exit_Proc:
Set cnn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set param = Nothing

Exit Function

Err_Handle:
    ' msgbox with details or whatever error handle you use
    AllocatePymt = -1
    GoTo Exit_Proc
End Function
```

The stored procedure (and in turn the function) return the number of rows updated (or with an `INSERT` the number of new rows) or returns -1 if an error occurs; calling it would be something like:

```
l = UpdateData(52,1234,"FooBar")
SelectCase l
Case Is > 0
    msgbox "Updated " & l & " rows"
Case 0
    Msgbox "No rows updated, but no error"
Case Else
    Msgbox "An error occurred, the transaction was rolled back"
End Select
```

This all works in `Access 2007` and `SQL Server 2005`, which is all I have available.